# On the nature of a series involving ratios and power of logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\dfrac {\log n}{\log (n+1)} \right)^{n^2\log n}$$ convergent? I tried to apply some test, or compare with known series, but with no success; it looks too complicated. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where did this series come from? is there a reason you think it might be convergent?

Comment: $\left[(1+\frac{\ln(n)-\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n+1)})^{\frac{ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)-\ln(n+1)}}\right]^{\frac{n^2\ln(n)(\ln(n)-
ln(n+1))}{\ln(n+1)}}$. Observe the first exponential goes to $e$ and the second exponent goes to $-\infty$ faster than $-n$.

Comment: It should converge. A quick look at the graph of $a_n$ shows it's way smaller than $\frac{1}{n^{1.1}}$. Now the hard job is playing with inequalities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a Taylor expansion to low-order terms:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\log n}{\log(n+1)}
&= \frac{\log n}{\log n+\log(1+\frac{1}{n})}
= \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n\log n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n\log n}\right)}
\\&= 1-\frac{1}{n\log n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n\log n}\right)
\end{align}$$
from which
$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\log n}{\log(n+1)}\right)^{n^2\log n}
&=\exp\left(n^2\log n\log\left(\frac{\log n}{\log(n+1)}\right)\right)
\\
&=\exp\left(n^2\log n\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n\log n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n\log n}\right)\right)\right)\\
&=\exp\left(n^2\log n\left(-\frac{1}{n\log n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n\log n}\right)\right)\right)\\
&=\exp\left(-n+o\left(n\right)\right)
=\frac{1}{e^{n+o(n)}}
\end{align}$$

Thus, by comparison, the series will **converge**, since $\sum_n \frac{1}{e^n}$ does.

Comment: (Note: by doing a Taylor series expansion to more terms, you can even have the slightly tighter estimate asymptotics $e^{-n+\frac{1}{2}+o(1)}$.)

Comment: also note the singularity for $n=1$ if you leave $0^0$ undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Note that
\begin{align*}
\left(\dfrac {\log n}{\log (n+1)} \right)^{n^2\log n}&=\left(1+\frac{\log(1+1/n)}{\log(n)}\right)^{-n^2\log n}\\&=
\exp\left(-n^2\log(n)\log\left(1+\frac{\log(1+1/n)}{\log(n)}\right)\right)\\
&=
\exp\left(-n\cdot n\log(n)\cdot\log\left(1+\frac{1+o(1)}{n\log(n)}\right)\right)\\
&=
\exp\left(-n(1+o(1)\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: I believe I was slightly faster this time :)

Comment: @Clement C. Very fast indeed!! (+1)